Estoy desarrollando una web api en asp.net core 8 y quiero recibir el tipo de una entidad owned en un endpoint
Estoy utilizando Ef Core y Azure Cosmos Db junto en el patrón Repository. Mi problema es que tengo una Owned entity "Reactions" la cual existe en otras entidades, como Post o Comment. Lo que necesito es hacer un endpoint genérico que me permita manipular las Reactions el cual reciba de alguna manera el padre de la misma. Ya que la Reaction puntual va a existir en otra entidad debido a que es Owned. Por ejemplo:
Post post = await _postRepository.GetByOid(oid);
Reaction reaction = post.Reactions.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Oid == reactionOid);

Comment comment = await _commentRepository.GetByOid(oid);
Reaction reaction = comment.Reactions.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Oid == reactionOid);

El objetivo final es un endpoint que me permita manipular la reacción recibiendo de alguna manera el tipo del padre así yo se que repository utilizar.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Edita la pregunta, agrega todos los detalles necesarios para que cualquiera pueda reproducir tu escenario: Clases, métodos. Del mismo modo, coloca el problema que tienes (me tira un error 500 cuando hago XYZ -> detalla los pasos). Aquí tienes más recomendaciones sobre cómo construir preguntas con altas chances de respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.
